# When is $f^*:T^*M\to T^*M$ an ergodic map for a diffeomorphism $f:M\to M$?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, sg.symplectic-geometry, ergodic-theory

Let  M be  a  differentiable  manifold  and  $f:M \to M$ be  a  diffeomorphism. Then $f$  induces  a  natural map $f^* :T^*M \to T^*M$.
The pull back  map  $f^*$ is  a  symplectomorphism wrt the standard symplectic structure of  the  cotangent bundle  $T^*M$. So it is a volum preserving map. Under what conditions is the  mapping $f^*$    an ergodic map? How can one write the  measure (associated to the  volum form of  $T^*M$) in the form of convex combination (or integral) of  some ergodic measures? Are there some relations  between these questions and  some  dynamical properties of $f:M \to M$?

Comment: Don't you need to assume there is compact subset of $T^*M$ invariant by $f^*$ and restrict the symplectic form to this subset in order to be able to have a finite measure space a properly define ergodicity?

Comment: @kvicente very interesting and necessary point. thank you I come back very soon

Comment: @kvicente what about isometric condition? namely we assume that f preserves a Riemannian metric However the volum form of the cotangent bundle is independent of any metric on M

Comment: @kvicente however i wonder if ergodicity can be defined in non finite measure too: a full measure set is a measurable set whose intersection with every compact set K has full measure $\mu(K)$

Comment: @kvicente but as you interestingly indicated invariant finit measure subsets of the cotangent bundle is a necessary point which can generates new interesting question

Comment: It is possible to define ergodicity in non-compact spaces, there are easily findable references for that. However, it is a delicate matter. Now, because of the way symplectomorphisms of the cotangent bundle work, in order for $f^*$ to be ergodic a necessary condition would be that any $K\subset M$ with $\bar{K}\neq M$ and invariant by $f$, must have empty interior. So, this forces $K$ to be a rather complicate set, probably a Cantor like set where $f$ behaves somehow like a horseshoe map.