# Smooth action on cotangent space of the plane

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, convex-geometry, group-actions, symplectic-topology

Assuming that $S^1$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by smooth maps (which are diffeomorphisms), the induced action on the cotangent bundle given by
$$g\cdot(x,\xi)=(g\cdot x,\varphi^∗_{g^{−1}}\xi)$$
acts via symplectomorphisms (where $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$, $\xi\in T^∗_\mathbb{R}^2$, and $\varphi_g$ is the map which acts as $x↦g\cdot x$). If the action on the base preserves a convex region $K\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, containing the origin and centrally symmetric ($x\in K$ iff $-x\in K$), is it true that the action on the cotangent space preserves $K\times K^{\circ}$ where $K^{\circ}$ is the dual convex body of $K$, i.e.
$$K^{\circ}:=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid \langle x,y\rangle\leq 1, \forall x \in K\}.$$

This is certainly true for $K$ being the ball, but I have not been able to draw either a positive or a negative answer in general. I would very much appreciate any help or suggestion.

Comment: What is  a  proof  for  the  case of  $K=$ ball

Comment: Maybe I should have been a little bit more specific, thanks for the question. In the ball, if you take the standard circle action given by rotation of angle $t$, this will lift to the cotangent bundle as a rotation too by angle $t$ (this is a linear action and to dualize it we take the inverse of the transpose). Given that the dual of the ball is the ball itself we have that the action preserves $K\times K^{\circle}$ .

Comment: What is  the roll of $S^1$ in your  question? I mean that is it  sensitive  wrt  circle? can  we restate the question for  $\mathbb{Z}$ action?

Comment: So  for  a  given  diffeomorphism of  $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ assume that $f(D)=D$ can one say that $f^*:$ maps  $D\times D^\circ$  to itself?

Comment: I think a standard notatio for  $f^*$ is  $f^*(x,y)=(f^{-1}(x), df(f^{-1}(x)).y$ slightly  different  from  what  you wrote in group action case

Comment: Is  not possible  a  diffeomorphism of  $\mathbb{R}^2 $ keeps the  disk invariant  but  has  a  very  larg  differential  at the origin then  disrupt the polar  dual  equation then  not  keep invariant  $K^\circ$?

Comment: So  I personally guess that the  answer is  not affirmative. In the rotation example you considered the differential  is  not big. But  in general the  invariance  of  D does  not implies that the  action has  a  small  differentiation

Comment: I don't think that such a diffeomorphism with large differential at the origin will clearly disrupt the dual of $K$ as you say, the thing about symplectic maps is that, heuristically, large deformations that you perform on the basis ($x_1,x_2$ coordinates), are compensated by the an inversally proportional deformation in the fiber ($y_1,y_2$ coordinates), so as the global deformation balances itself, so if we still preserve the basis, I don't see why we could not preserve the fiber. I need more convincing beyond hand-waving arguments with that approach.

Comment: Answering your first question, the role of the $S^1$-action is crucial for applying some other symplectic geometry arguments, replacing it with a $\mathbb{Z}_p$ action would render those other arguments useless. But your question is a good start, is a necessary condition for my question to be positive

Comment: To  have  a  true  understanding of  your  previous 2  comments I need  to  confirm that  by  $K^\circ$ you  mean  $\{y\mid y.x\leq 1 \forall  x\in K$  yes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148853/discussion-between-kvicente-and-ali-taghavi).

Comment: By invariance of the pairing, this is true if the derivative of the action, viewed as $\phi'_g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ preserves $K$. In particular, it works for linear actions (generalizing your example of the rotation action). If I'm not mistaken, the condition on $\phi'$ is also necessary: if there is a $z \in K$ such that $\phi'_g z$ is not again in $K$ for some $g$, then choose $y \in K^0$ with $y (\phi'_g z) = 2$. But then $\phi^*_g y$ has value $2$ at $z$, showing that it is not an element of $K^0$.

Comment: I think you are right @TobiasDiez, thanks for your comment it as really helpful!

Comment: @kvicente  Any way the  question was  interesting however the differential can destroy  what you desire.  But  your  question is  motivating  some  other question: First  what is  a diffeomorphism of the plane  not  coming  from a  circle  action because I  understood you emphasis o circle action? Another question which  I am thinking to(as a  generalization of materials  you  pointed out to) is  to nonlinearize the  concept of  dual:  Let $M$  be a  Riemannian manifild  and $K$ is  a  submanifold of  $M$ then one  may  define

Comment: $K^\circ=\{\zeta \in T^*K\mid \zeta(v)\leq 1  \forall v\in T^1_p K,  \forall p\in K$ where $T^1$ is the unit or  disk tangent bundle of  K.

Comment: Then  ask  under  what  conditions  the  dual is invariant under the  dual (pull) back map

Comment: regarding the  first  question I guess that  $f$ must have  a  chaotic dynamics or it must  be  a  finite  order diffeomorphisms. BTW  can  one  characterize  all linear  isomorphisms of the  Euclidean space whose  dynamics  comes  from  a  circle  action?

Comment: and  do they  form  a  subgroup of the  general linear group?

Comment: @AliTaghavi Diffeomorphisms coming from a circle action are isotopic (by diffeoemorphisms) to the identity, I'm not sure if in the plane every diffeoemorphism is isotopic to the identity, or said otherwise, the group $Diff(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is connected. Try for example to connect $(x,y)\to(-x,y)$ to the identity via diffeoemorphisms. The emphasis of the circle action is basically that instead of just one diffeomorphisms I have an $S^1$-family of diffeomorphisms. Now, this $K^{\circ}$ that you define in the Riemannian sense is no other that the disk cotangent bundle of K, by definition.

Comment: and to get the invariance I'm pretty sure is basically, the equivalent to this setitng, of @TobiasDiez condition on the differential.

Comment: @kvicente   the isotopy you are talking  about  works  for  both  R action and  circle  action so I mean  what  is the raeson (and  difference)  for  emphasis  on  circle action

Comment: In the other word what  is  a  map (time  one  map  of  flow) on the plane  which does not come  from a  circle  action?

Comment: Any way  your  question has  a beautiful philosophy when certain property of  f on M carries to the  same  property  for  f^* on the  cotangent bundle. on can ask some  questions of this  type in for example Ergodic theory. Assume  f  is  ergodic  is  the pull back an ergodic map too? please see the  following:

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451247/when-is-ftm-to-tm-an-ergodic-map-for-a-diffeomorphism-fm-to-m